Why bother bringing the rod to speak to the rock?
In Numbers 20:8, the Israelites need water, so God tells Moses: Take this rod and talk to this rock and it will yield water.  Moses hits the rock with the rod and water comes out.  God gets angry and tells Moses: Because you hit the rock instead of talking to it, you will not enter the Promised Land.
What was the rod for?

He whacked the rock, rather than talking to it. He was also 120 at this point, so his staff may have been because Hashem didn't want him to fall down

The rod was a symbol of authority, nobody could lift it but Moshe.

Good question! All the miracles were done with the staff. (At least) the first ten were actually carved into it. - Another good place to ask the question: Moshe overseeing the battle with Amalek, "ומטה האלהים בידי".
